# Kibana Index pattern refresh option is no longer there

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I used to refresh the index patterns by doing

Go inside Kibana (Management > Index patterns), select the index pattern, and press the "Refresh" button at the top right of the window in order to pick up the mapping changes.

However, now that option is missing .

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [since 7.11](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.11/whats-new.html#index-patterns-refresh), Kibana does the refresh automatically for you, no need to do it manually, it's done automatically whenever a new field is added to your index.

You can read more about the context of this change in [PR #82223](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/pull/82223)

Comment: Thank you so much, I saw in an early answer of yours, that , https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html , seems that also no needed , since now it's automatically refreshed.

Comment: and it seems not working at all :/

Comment: @ThomasDecaux maybe create a new question describing your issue. "not working at all" doesn't help much